sObject Get Deleted return HTTP Status Code 400
I build a data replication system using SF Rest API (with token) and I already have several processes that query and "write" SF successfully.
I'm trying to implement the sObject Get Deleted and I'm testing a request like this example :
/sobjects/Account/deleted/​​​?start=2024-09-22T12%3A43%3A12%2B00%3A00&end=2024-10-07T12%3A43%3A12%2B00%3A00

All the part before sobjects is omitted but present in real world
I try with diferent types of data formatting but the response in always :

HTTP Status Code: 400 Bad Request

EDIT after RubenDG comments
In order to detail the errorCode I try some curl (with token):
curl --request GET "https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v62.0/sobjects/Account/deleted/?start=2024-09-23T12%3A43%3A33%2B00%3A00&end=2024-10-07T12%3A43%3A33%2B00%3A00" -H "Authorization: Bearer ..."

returns

[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]

I try with different sObjects but nothing change. Then I try with diffrent API version
curl --request GET "https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v60.0/sobjects/Account/deleted/?start=2024-09-23T12%3A43%3A33%2B00%3A00&end=2024-10-07T12%3A43%3A33%2B00%3A00" -H "Authorization: Bearer ..."

returns

{"deletedRecords":[],"earliestDateAvailable":"2024-06-29T07:43:00.000+0000","latestDateCovered":"2024-10-07T12:43:00.000+0000"}

So it seems to be an API version issue not a date format issue

Could you please try
/sobjects/Account/deleted/​​​?start=2024-09-22T12:43:12.000&end=2024-10-07T12:43:12.000

@Hariprasath : you mean without URLEncoding? I'm pretty sure it won't work

Refer this link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_valid_date_formats.htm
/sobjects/Account/deleted/​​​?start=2024-09-22T12:43:12Z&end=2024-10-07T12:43:12Z

Even if your datetime values are in ISO 8601 format, that API mandates the UTC timezone, so you must use Z instead +00:00. Docs (emphasis mine):

Starting date/time (Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)—not local— timezone) of the timespan for which to retrieve the data. The API ignores the seconds portion of the specified dateTime value (for example, 12:30:15 is interpreted as 12:30:00 UTC). The date and time must be formatted as described in Valid Date and DateTime Formats.

The other link states

'Z' is the reference UTC timezone

To fix this issue is enough changing those values to:
deleted/​​​?start=2024-09-22T12:43:12Z&end=2024-10-07T12:43:12Z


Thanks Ruben, both the "Z" format of the doc and the "+" format of the example (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_get_deleted.htm) returns the same status code

@AlexMI Which API version are you using? I tested it with both 60 and 61. What's the errorCode? Did you try without encoding the query parameters?

I edit my question after your comment to integate some other test

@AlexMI All's well that ends well. Anyway if I try with APIv62 (my org is at 61) I get "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND", but the status code is 404, not 400, while if I send "+00:00" without encoding it I get "errorCode": "INVALID_DATE_FORMAT" and status code 400

You inspire me once again ... trying several curl I can confirm that with v62.0 the errorCode is NOT_FOUND. With other versions the response is always correct with both date format and even with or without the slash between deleted and the ? of query string. Now I'm struggling investigating the Bad Request response...
